# ASP.NET MVC does not understand mixed url encoding (UTF-8/Latin-1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-encoding

I have two URLs with parameters

```
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=CyanГ
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyanì
```

In first URL Firefox encodes last charecter (Г) as %D0%93 (correctly in UTF-8).
In second URL Firefox encodes last character (ì) as %EC (correctly in ISO-8859-1)

ASP.NET MVC can be configured using  element in web.config to either assume UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. But Firefox flips between encodings depending on the context.

Note that UTF-8 can be unambiguously distinguished from Latin-1 encoding.

Is there a way to teach ASP.NET MVC to decode parameter values using either one of the formats?

**EDIT:** Is there a class that I could use to decode raw query string that would handle encoding correctly? Note - Firefox uses either UTF-8 **or** Latin-1 encoding - but not both at the same time. So my plan is to try decode manually using UTF-8 and then look for "invalid" character (FFFD), if one is found - try Latin-1 decode.

Example:

Firefox encodes as following:

```
-                                          v   v
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=ArcânisГ 
Firefox turns into  
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arc%C3%A2nis%D0%93`
```

Notice that `UTF8` encoding is used for both non-ASCII characters.

```
-                                          v
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arcâ
Firefox turns into
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arc%E2
```

Notice that `ISO-8859-1` (Latin-1) encoding is used for the non-ASCII character.

Comment: Do you specify the proper charset in the response headers or in the HTML page for the referrer?

Comment: I just enter the URL in the browser, and in my action(string name) - name end up being encoded incorrectly. So the problem occurs before either charset or referrer have to play a part.

Comment: Yeah but the only way a URL will end up in the browser will be from a link on your website. So you can just URL encode them in your views to your liking, that way no un-encoded characters will end up in the browser url.

Comment: no. user can enter the url in the browser directly with non-ascii characters

Comment: Why would a user do that? Is it part of your website strategy to get users to enter URLs manually? Read: is it worth investing time in that scenario?

Comment: I want user to be able to copy the link and then paste it. After user fills out the form it submits the form using GET which puts the parameter in the URL. But if user copy-pastes it - it will get encoded. So user doesn't really builds the URL manually, but user can paste it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution, any way to improve on it? Specifically I would rather extend framework instead of handling it inside an action itself.

```
    private string DecodeNameParameterFromQuery(string query) {
        string nameUtf8 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query, Encoding.UTF8)["name"];
        const char invalidUtf8Character = (char) 0xFFFD;
        if (nameUtf8.Contains(invalidUtf8Character)) {
            const int latin1 = 0x6FAF;
            var nameLatin1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query, Encoding.GetEncoding(latin1))["name"];
            return nameLatin1;
        }
        return nameUtf8;
    }
```