# ASP.NET MVC parse URL query part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urldecode

I want something to turn `?a=5&b=8` part of a URL into a dictionary { a:5, b:8 }.

Is there such method in .net or am I on my own?

I need to parse query part so that I can implement my own URL decoding.
The problem is that Firefox uses different encoding (UTF8 or ISO-8859-1) depending on the used alphabet.

Example:

Firefox encodes as following:

```
-                                          v   v
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=ArcânisГ 
Firefox turns into  
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arc%C3%A2nis%D0%93`
```

Notice that `UTF8` encoding is used for both non-ASCII characters.

```
-                                          v
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arcâ
Firefox turns into
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Arc%E2
```

Notice that `ISO-8859-1` (Latin-1) encoding is used for the non-ASCII character.

Here is a related question: [ASP.NET MVC does not understand mixed url encoding (UTF-8/Latin-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168636/asp-net-mvc-does-not-understand-mixed-url-encoding-utf-8-latin-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request.QueryString is a NameValueCollection that is like a dictionary.

It can contain multiple values for the same key.

If "?a=5&b=8" not come from querystring you can use **HttpUtility.ParseQueryString** method to get a NameValueCollection

If you want a true dictionary:

```
var d = new Dictionary<String,Object>();
this.Request.QueryString.CopyTo(d);
```

Comment: The problem with Request.QueryString is that it also unescapes values, it is unescaping that I need to handle. Details: firefox can use utf-8 OR latin-1 to escape characters, but ASP.Net MVC uses one or the other all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a custom modelbinder to handle dictionaries? It seems like relying on the querystring, while perfectly valid, goes against the spirit of the framework. It also may make testing your action a little more difficult.

My first thought was that this was already handled by the default modelbinder facilites, but this doesn't appear to be the case. That said, I haven't tried it but this is where I'd start:

[An Intuitive Dictionary Model Binder for ASPnet MVC](http://siphon9.net/loune/2009/12/a-intuitive-dictionary-model-binder-for-asp-net-mvc/)